# Maintain session on GridView Checkbox oncheckchange

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session, gridview

I am keeping DataTable in session variable.

A **GridView** having template column checkbox with **autopostback** set to true. 
**oncheckchange** event of checkbox is tracked to delete or add rows in **session DataTable**.

Application opens multiple instances of same page and respective GridView on page is source for adding or deleting rows in (one for all) session DataTable.

> Now problem is that I cannot click fast on checboxes in a gridview.
>   Apparently it look like server side process of updating session table is very
>   slow. Sometimes cached clicks come into action quite slowly. **Please guide how to maintain session DataTable efficiently?**

Note:

I have checkbox in the header row of every GridView as well, which checks and un-checks every row present in Gridview.

Comment: use ajax for delete and edit data it would be perform more faster then posting whole page in postback

Comment: I am using ajax for the purpose.
GridView in UpdatePanel with updatemode set to conditional. Whole page is not refreshed oncheckchange.

Comment: use viewstate instead  of session another tip for same page